# Downloading a Google document as an HTML page: image names

Tags: google-docs, images

When downloading a Google document as an HTML page, the images are stored in an "images" folder with formatted names: "image00.png", "image01.png", etc. What determines the ordering of the image names?

From what I can see, it doesn't seem to depends on the order in which the images have been inserted in the document. It also doesn't reflect the order of the images in the Google document.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it highly depends om how the document is actually stored by Google and is subject to change between the releases of the backend and frontend.

I guess (out of my developmemt experience) that images are kept in something like a hash table where index order is not really well defined and can change based on the inner workings of the data structure instance (from doc to doc and even from one export of the doc to the other).